# Oracle SQLDeveloper: Keep CR LF on insert

Tags: export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to export and import some data in my oracle DB.

Using Export, I choose Format insert and default settings. This gives me a Windows file with correct CR LF within cells.

However, when I open this file in the SQLDeveloper and run the inserts all will be stored in DB only with LF.

How can I keep the CR LF?

For scripting reasions I require the insert statements.

Comment: When exporting data, there's the "Line Terminator" option which allows you to select "Windows CR LF". Did you do that? (Yes, I know, you mentioned that "that gives you a Windows file with correct CR LF within cells", but I'm not sure whether we are talking about the same thing).

Comment: Yes, I did. I ended up converting the inserts for CRLF to ||chr(13)||chr(10)

Comment: Any solution is better than no solution :) Thank you for the feedback!